# UICollectionView rendered taller than in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView in a storyboard (iPad).  I'm not setting any properties (margins, sizes etc.) programatically - my delegate only implements the mandatory methods (number of sections & items, cellForItemAtIndexPath).  I'm using the standard flow layout, with horizontal scrolling (1 row), and no top/bottom insets.  I have a custom cell class, but again, nothing fancy (just IBOutlets for some labels and an imageView).  My cells are 100x100px.  The collectionView has its height set to 100px, and IB shows it as such.

[image: attributes inspector]
[image: size inspector]

However, when I run the app I get the collectionView rendered as 140px in height (with a 20px margin above and below the cells).  I played with different values for all properties (including the min spacing) but couldn't make the view any shorter - I can only make it taller by changing the insets.

Is this a bug or am I missing some logic that I cannot circumvent, e.g. the standard layout will forcefully include some minimum spacing above & below its contents?

Comment: Not at all. I haven't tried though, I just considered it a bug in collection view and moved on at the time. If you do find a solution please post here as well, I'd most definitely appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using autolayout, are there some constraints for the collection view? If you are using autolayout the frames you see on IB aren't necessary the same when you run the app because the frames are calculated based on the constraints, screen size and device orientation etc. The `UICollectionView` cell sizes or inset values are not related to the bounds of the collection view itself (will print errors if they don't fit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was to disable "adjust scroll view insets" on the view controller that has the collection view.

Comment: I accepted your answer since I'm not in a position to check right now, but I appreciate your help (plus the solution actually makes sense).